# Elementary OS, No sound. Tried all possible troubleshooting

Tags: sound, audio

Good day mates,
I'm a new user to Linux and recently installed Elementary OS on 2014 machine Asus eeebook x205ta.
After instalation everything worked well except for no sound.
I tried all this commands listed on forums and also youtube, but no avail.
I tried fiddling around with Alsamixer and pulse audio too.
I'm getting two audio outputs analog / multimedia but still I don't have any sound.
I'm ready to provide more information, kindly assist me.

Comment: That particular notebook has a history of audio problems on Linux. That said, there is [an unofficial patch](https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-16.04-install-asus-x205ta.md#experimental-kernel-changes-for-audio-support) that may get you working. The instructions are for Ubuntu, but may work on your system as well. Unfortunately I do not have an x205TA to test this with ... 

Comment: hi slevin can i ask you how did you manage to install elementary on x205ta? I have tried many times without success